# Change minimum upload part size of minio server

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

there is a limitation of 5MB per part of multipart upload on S3 API. Is there any solution to change this limitation on minio?

Comment: I opened an issue for them and they told there is no plan to change this limitation: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/8022#event-2531210239

Answer (score 0):

This limit is sadly hard-coded, mixed in with the code of the `utils.go` module, so a fork and [installation from source](https://github.com/minio/minio#install-from-source) ("only intended for developers and advanced users") is required to change it:

```golang
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html
const (
    // Maximum object size per PUT request is 5TB.
    // This is a divergence from S3 limit on purpose to support
    // use cases where users are going to upload large files
    // using 'curl' and presigned URL.
    globalMaxObjectSize = 5 * humanize.TiByte

    // Minimum Part size for multipart upload is 5MiB
    globalMinPartSize = 5 * humanize.MiByte

    // Maximum Part ID for multipart upload is 10000
    // (Acceptable values range from 1 to 10000 inclusive)
    globalMaxPartID = 10000
)
```

[ https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/cmd/utils.go#L251 ]

Comment: I did the same on those years :D and it actually wasn't that good, had some serious pressure on the disks ( not on SSD ), so I managed to implement shorter part-sizes in a proxy that I wrote between my client and minio ( saving parts for a short time on memory instead of disk ).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this limitation without recompiling the server - it is configurable on the client side, e.g. in the open-source S3-compatible `minio` client we can customize the `part_size` argument of `fput_object`:

```py
# default setting of `globalMinPartSize` is 5 MiB:
# multipart_size_bytes = 5 * (1024)**2

# but here we increase it 10-fold:
multipart_size_bytes = 50 * (1024)**2

# and then we can upload a 50 MiB file to a S3 / minio bucket in one chunk
minio_client.fput_object([..],
                         part_size=multipart_size_bytes)
```